# Is there an algorithm for listing all/minimum admissable sets in a graph that satisfies the backdoor criterion in Causal Inference?

Tags: algorithms, causality

I would like to know if there exists an algorithm for finding all/minimum admissible sets in a graph that satisfy the backdoor criterion as defined by [Judea Pearl in his book Causality](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052189560X) (Please see [here](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/ch3-3.pdf)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I'm not sure about the algorithm, but it is currently implemented in the [dagitty](http://www.dagitty.net/) tool. If you enter your proposed DAG, it will list the adjustment sets for a given total causal effect. More details are offered on the homepage about how the algorithm works, with relevant papers.

Comment: Noah, dagitty does not list all admissible sets,  it lists the minimal sufficient sets.

Comment: Actually, minimal sufficient sets works also for me. My bad, I should have made the question more specific. Just my first question here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are, the most recent development I am aware of is from [Correa and Bareinboim](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/eb/r24.pdf), which provides:

> a complete algorithm with polynomial delay to find all sets of
>   admissible covariates for adjustment when confounding and selection
>   biases are simultaneously present and unbiased data is available.

It finds not only for backdoor adjustment, but also considering possible selection biases.